# how do I install Ubuntu on a Macbook Pro 2011 (Early) without any third party apps?

Tags: macosx

I would like to know if I can install Ubuntu on my MBPro without any third party apps. I mean, for example set up bootcamp and in the free partition install ubuntu with no problems, any suggestions? I dont wanna triple boot OSX Win7 and Ubuntu, just OSX and Ubuntu. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you'll need [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) to be able to do the dual boot.